# Best web specific spell checker for the .NET platform?

Tags: asp.net, spell-checking

We are currently looking at the product listed below, but I thought to see what others are using.

http://www.aspnetspell.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Infragistics WinForm SpellChecker in the past and it works good.

Here is a link to their ASP WebSpellChecker

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/webspellchecker.aspx#Overview

Answer (score 1):

If you still find it interesting, have a look at this WebSpellCheker, here is the link - http://www.spellchecker.net/